# Add button dynamically to html table on row append to other table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below code is working well to append row from one html table to other. But i want to add button dynamically to append row as well.

```
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
   onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
    if (index == 1) {
        $('#tblPurchaseOrders').find('tr:has(td)').each(function() {
            if (parseInt(($(this).find('#Quantity')).val()) > 0)
                $(this).appendTo('#tbOrderDetail');
        });
    }
}
 });
```

working example is on below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/x4k7yhye/17/

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? Please explain. Also please show your complete code.

Comment: I am trying to append row from one html table to other. Above code is working well. But i want to add button with append row as well.

Comment: Check my answer below. If that's what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but you can check this script. I have added Add button in new table's action column.

### HTML

```
<div id="rootwizard">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#details" data-toggle="tab">details</a></li>
          <li><a href="#captain" data-toggle="tab">captain</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="details">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h4 class="info-text">
            Let's start with the basic details.
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="persons">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="tblPurchaseOrders">
                  <tr>
                    <th>
                      Product Code
                    </th>
                    <th>
                      SKU
                    </th>
                    <th>
                      Product Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                      Quantity
                    </th>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name="ProductCode" value="A" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name="SKU" value="A1" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name="Name1" value="A1" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>


                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name="ProductCode" value="B" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name="SKU" value="B1" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name="Name1" value="B1" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" id="Quantity" value="1" class="form-control" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="captain">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="tbOrderDetail">
              <tr>
                <th>
                  Product Code
                </th>
                <th>
                  SKU
                </th>
                <th>
                  Product Name
                </th>
                <th>
                  Quantity
                </th>
                <th>
                  Action
                </th>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="pager wizard">
      <li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="#">First</a></li>
      <li class="previous"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
      <li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Last</a></li>
      <li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">

</div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
    onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {

      if (index == 1) {
        $('#tblPurchaseOrders').find('tr:has(td)').each(function() {
          if (parseInt(($(this).find('#Quantity')).val()) > 0){
          $(this).append("<td><input type='button' class='btn' value='Add' /></td>");
            $(this).appendTo('#tbOrderDetail');
            }
        });        
      }

    }
  });
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/x4k7yhye/52/)

Let me know if that's your desired output?

### Update

Revert it back.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
    onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {

      if (index == 1) {
        $('#tblPurchaseOrders').find('tr:has(td)').each(function() {
          if (parseInt(($(this).find('#Quantity')).val()) > 0){
          $(this).append("<td><input type='button' class='btn revertButton' value='Revert' /></td>");
            $(this).appendTo('#tbOrderDetail');
            }
        });        
      }

    }
  });

  $(document).on("click",".revertButton",function(){
    var tr = $(this).parents("tr");
    tr.find(".revertButton").parents("td").remove();
    $("#tblPurchaseOrders").append(tr);
  });
});
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/3ev5jmq1/9/)

### Update 2

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
    onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {

      if (index == 1) {
        $('#tblPurchaseOrders').find('tr:has(td)').each(function() {
          if (parseInt(($(this).find('#Quantity')).val()) > 0){
          $(this).append("<td><input type='button' class='btn revertButton' value='Revert' /></td>");
            $(this).appendTo('#tbOrderDetail');
            }
        });        
      }

    }
  });

  $(document).on("click",".revertButton",function(){
    var tr = $(this).parents("tr");
    tr.find(".revertButton").parents("td").remove();
    tr.find("#Quantity").val(0);
    $("#tblPurchaseOrders").append(tr);
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/3ev5jmq1/11/)

Comment: @Samit Raval. Your script work good. Is it possible if i click on added button the append row revert back to original table. thanks

Comment: @Samit Rava: Thanks dear you really solved my problem. Bundle of thanks. One thing more can we change the quantity to zero on revert.

Comment: Check for update 2 in my answer. And welcome. :) @user3828909

Comment: Hi smith need your help...I want to do inline editing on append row to other table.

Comment: @Samit Raval I am new to jquery therefore i cannot do much. Please help me out.

Comment: What kind of inline editing you want to do? It's already editable. @user3828909

Comment: I want to add button edit with append row and when i click edit button it only show quantity in editable mode.

Comment: So by default no field will be editable in second table. You need to add one more button with revert called edit? When you click on edit only Quantity should be editable? Is that what you want? @user3828909

Comment: its not working. Quantity should only be editable if i click edit. Other wise it should be ready only

Comment: Can we do something like edit on link: https://jsfiddle.net/b5w53yoo/1/

Comment: Will update the link once I get some time. @user3828909

Comment: thanks for your time and you are really making me learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Jquery, it is easy to use than pure javascript (i think so):

```
    <tr id="row1"><td>....</td>
<td><button class="clickme" row-tag="row1">Your button</button></td></tr>

    .....row2,row3....

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).on('click','.clickme',function(){
          var self = $(this);
          //get your <tr> by id:

          var yourtr = $("#"+self.attr("row-tag"));

          //do something with this tr

       })
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is not so clear, so I assumed that you want to add a button that allows to add a new row, and then another button to append it to the next table.

This is how I did it:

```
<table class="templatetbl">
  <tr class="template">
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="ProductCode" value="A" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="SKU" value="A1" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="Name1" value="A1" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="appendRow" value="Append row" class="form-control" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I added a hidden template for the row and added a new button called "New Row":
`<a class="newRow form-control" href="#">New row</a>`

This following codes add the new row from template and move it to the next table on button click:

```
$(".newRow").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".template").clone(true, true).appendTo('#tblPurchaseOrders').show().removeClass("template");
  });

  $(".table").on("click", "#appendRow", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").detach().appendTo("#tbOrderDetail").find("td").last().remove();
  });
```

The added CSS are only these:

```
.templatetbl {
  display: none;
}

.template {
  display: none;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u3a3Lcm9/)